# Object gets stuck after collision

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have two rectangle objects that originate from a point and is moved using the mouse. The collision code works perfectly but when the objects collide the object suddenly becomes immovable.

```
//Here is my collision code
bool collision(GLPoint A, GLPoint B)
{
    //Width/Height
    int w = 150;
    int h = 150;

    //Sides of A Rectangle
    int leftA = A.x;
    int rightA = A.x+w;
    int topA = A.y;
    int bottomA = A.y+h;

    //Sides of B Rectangle
    int leftB = B.x;
    int rightB = B.x+w;
    int topB = B.y;
    int bottomB = B.y+h;

    if(bottomA <= topB)
        return false;
    if(topA >= bottomB)
        return false;
    if(rightA <= leftB)
        return false;
    if(leftA >= rightB)
        return false;

    return true;
    /*
    if(ALeft <= BRight)
        return true;
    else
        return false;*/
}
```

Here is my code where I move the object if the mouse is inside the rectangle. If the mouse is not colliding I am able to move it. However, when the object collides with the other rectangle it gets stuck. Here is a picture of the object before it collides. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf1wb.jpg

After it collides: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf3gV.jpg.

```
static int x=iarray[0].x;
static int y=iarray[0].y;
//Set points of 1st Instance
if(mouseX > iarray[0].x && mouseX < iarray[0].x +150 && 750-mouseY < iarray[0].y && 750-mouseY > iarray[0].y-150)
{
    if(collision(iarray[0], iarray[1]))
    {
        cout << "COLLIDING" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NOT COLLIDING" << endl;
        x = mouseX-75, y = 750-mouseY+50;               
    }

    iarray[0].set(x,y);
}
```

Comment: If it's colliding then you probably still want to change the x,y coordinates. Move the line "x = mouseX-75, y = 750-mouseY+50" out of the else block otherwise it will only be moved when it's not colliding.

Comment: This is typically solved by studying the logic of state transitions -- a) allow moving a body to positions, which do not collide. b) if you allow collision to happen, you should allow an object to move towards a non-colliding position (if everything else fails, you can store the previous position, when everything was ok).

Comment: instead of checking the current move you could check the future position, so add an offset to the rectangle in the direction that you want to move to

Comment: @Xonar, I'm not sure exactly where I would move the rectangle to exactly. I've tried multiple ways to move it somewhere where it doesn't collide but it isn't very precise. I want it to be able to detect if it hits the left side and move outwards from the leftside. Do you think I should expand my collision method?

Comment: @Anton and Aki
How would I implement an offset. Would I have to make a slightly bigger rectangle that surrounds the colliding rectangle and see if that collides?

Comment: yes that's what i mean by that, try to implement that and if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @AntonD Thank you for your help I did exactly what you told me and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking the current position, you should check the position in the future and decide if you can move. In other words: make the bounding rectangle bigger but not the actual thing which you draw.